# how to use table elements

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I'm displaying titles of movies as letter images e.g. A separate image for each letter. Each letter can then be dragged in a space/container. this is my code for displaying the container

```
posX = {}
posY = 124
px = 10
containers = {}
for i = 1, #letters do
    if(letters[i]==" ") then
        px = px + 10
        -- print(posX[i])
        -- table.remove(posX, posX[i])
    else
    posX[i] = px
    containers[i] = display.newImage( "Round1_blue_tileEnlarged 40x40.png",      posX[i],posY )
    px = px + 40
    end
end
```

As you can see I am checking for a space e.g if batman begins was the title, I have no problems if the title is a single word, but adding the space is adding another element to my array that is causing an error when im placing an objecet in my containers. You can see in the 'if' im just adding a space but I dont want this to be an element of my table posX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question well but if I do here is your problem: you are using `i` as the index in `posX` but `i` is incremented by the for loop even for spaces. That results in holes in the `posX` and `containers` tables.

You can fix that in several ways, here is a trivial one:

```
posX = {}
posY = 124
px = 10
containers = {}
local j = 1
for i = 1,#letters do
    if(letters[i]==" ") then
        px = px + 10
    else
        posX[j] = px
        containers[j] = display.newImage( "Round1_blue_tileEnlarged 40x40.png", posX[j],posY )
        px = px + 40
        j = j + 1
    end
end
```

You could also use `#posX` instead of `j`.

Comment: thank you! I have been looking at this so long, I couldn't see the simple solution